# Different path separators during FTP transaction between windows and linux

Tags: java, ftp

I am uploading a file via FTP to a Linux server. I use Apache's [`FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

So let's say I wanted to upload the file `C:\\downloads\\13\\myFile.txt` to the server at `/data/downloads/13/myFile.txt`

Before I upload, I determine whether the directory that it will be sent to exists using `listFiles`.

When I say

```
ftp.listFiles("/data/downloads/13");
```

I get an array containing one file object, meaning that the path exists (and I don't need to create a folder). However when I say

```
ftp.listFiles("\\data\\downloads\\13");
```

I get an empty array, meaning the path does not exist.

The reason for this is because I'm running my application from a Windows machine, so the path separator is different.

The solution I've decided on is to normalize the paths by replacing `\` with `/` before I proceed with the FTP transactions.

Is this the proper way to address this issue?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm somewhat concerned of the possibility that someone actually does change the server to something that does not accept `/` and then tells me that my code is broken! Only somewhat, because I don't think there exists such a system.

Comment: @PeterLawrey FTP provides an abstract view into some filesystem, so the separator is "/" because this is what the FTP protocol defines, not what the host OS expects (even if you run some FTP server on Windows, it is "/")

Comment: @GyroGearless Thank you for the correction. All OSes should sue '/' anyway. ;)

Comment: @gyrogearless There's no standard pathname pattern in FTP. Some can and will use "\". Rebex for example uses whatever the local SO is using.

Answer (score 2):

From RFC 959:

> pathname
>
> ```
>      Pathname is defined to be the character string which must be
>      input to a file system by a user in order to identify a file.
>      Pathname normally contains device and/or directory names, and
>      file name specification.  FTP does not yet specify a standard
>      pathname convention.  Each user must follow the file naming
>      conventions of the file systems involved in the transfer.
> ```

Because there is no pathname standard, an FTP server can choose to use the pathname conventions of their local file system if they wish. You may wish to send a SYST request to the server before you modify your pathname if you intend to connect to any other server.

```
4.1.3.  FTP SERVICE COMMANDS
     ...
     SYSTEM (SYST)

            This command is used to find out the type of operating
            system at the server.  The reply shall have as its first
            word one of the system names listed in the current version
            of the Assigned Numbers document [4].
```

The SYST command is not required for minimum FTP server implementation, so this command may be unrecognized by some servers. But if the command has been implemented, it will allow you to modify your pathname to be compatible. Here are 5 example responses you may receive:

```
 215 UNIX Type: L8
 215 UNIX Type: L8 Version: BSD-44
 215 NetWare system type.
 215 MACOS Peter's Server
 215 AmigaOS
```

From the Apache FTPClient documentation you have linked to, the function that sends a SYST request is this I believe, although I am unfamiliar with Java and this Apache client: [getSystemType](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getSystemType%28%29).

And lastly an [example](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-example-get-status-of-system-directory-and-file).

But yes, if the server only supports a UNIX pathname you are going to have to convert your Windows pathname from '\' to '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Its the proper way to use the ' / ' but dont know the idea why you want to replace the path seperator before the FTP transactions.But you are running from windows you can provide your full path of windows file as a source with the ' / ' and you can use "/data/downloads/13" as your target.

Provide somemore clarification if I misunderstood it.

Comment: The path separator is replaced/normalized because the target folder is generated from the source folder, which uses windows-style path separators.